# sketch region bounded by 4 functions

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to find the area of the region bounded by the functions

$y=sin(x^2)$, $ y=0$, $ x=1$, $ x=2$

I've graphed the functions and my hunch is that I'm to bound the region above the $x$-axis from $1$ to $\sqrt{\pi}$ then the small region below the $x$-axis from $\sqrt{\pi}$ to $2$.  From there I will use the integration formula for the shell method to find the volume of the solid created when the region is rotated about the y-axis.

I would like to know if I am shading the correct regions

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should not consider the region$(\sqrt(\pi),2]$. If you do, it will give you a negative integral. If you want to consider also that in the revolution, you should change its sign.

Comment: Good point.  I think this question confuses me because I'm used to seeing 2 or 3 functions and the area bounded is bounded by all functions simultaneously, while in this case the first region I mentioned is only bound by $3$ out of $4$ of the functions while the second area is similarly bound .  Is this something I should not worry about?  And if that's the case should I then proceed as you have suggested?

Comment: Perhaps I should interpret $x=1$ and $x=2$ as the limits of integration?

Comment: I believe you mean that you want to find the volume generated by revolving this region about the y-axis, in which case you would have two integrals, one with $1\le x\le\sqrt{\pi}$ and the second with $\sqrt{\pi}\le x\le 2$.

Comment: a) $x=1$ and $x=2$ are to be interpreted as the bounds of $x$ in the integral (summing in $dx$)

Comment: b) the volume, in the geometrical sense, shall be understood as always positive, so you should integrate the abs value of the $y(x)$ or change the sign in the part. However, algebraically and sometimes in physics it makes sense to consider the "volume" with its positive or negative values. I do not know which is your case.